# How to constrain a stereotype to have no attributes?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I tried using OCL but this doesn't actually work in EA.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What **exactly** did you try ? What **exactly** doesn't work in EA ? Some [steps-to-reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Actually a demo is not needed here since EA does not interpret OCL. In general @xmojmr is right and you should post that with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way in EA is to write an add-in doing the check. EA only checks the OCL syntax, but does not execute it.